# Programmatically setting individual grades in D2L?

Tags: desire2learn

How are grades set for a particular assignment or quiz via REST/Valence API in D2L?

Answer (score 0):

There are calls to [set final "grade values"](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#put--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-grades-final-values-%28D2LID-userId%29), and calls to [set grade values for specific](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#put--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-grades-%28D2LID-gradeObjectId%29-values-%28D2LID-userId%29) gradeable objects. You can also get a [list of the "gradeable objects"](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#get--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-grades-)